# How can I make new variables out of elements in a list?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 3 lines. I want to efficiently separate each line out as it’s own individual item.

```
myList = [MultiLine.attributes.renderers[0], MultiLine.attributes.renderers[1],
MultiLine.attributes.renderers[2]]
```

What I want:

```
    line1 = MultiLine.attributes.renderers[0];
    line2 = MultiLine.attributes.renderers[1];
    line3 = MultiLine.attributes.renderers[2];
```

I know in Python there is the casting function which I would use like so:

```
line + str(i) = MultiLine.attributes.renderers[i];
```

However I'm getting **ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side** with the equivalent JS:

```
for(var j = 0; j < myList.length; j++){
    "line" + String(j) = MultiLine.attributes.renderers[j];
    }
```

Any ideas?

I don't know how to properly go about changing the value of my variable within the for-loop. Would Break statements help?

Comment: 1) You can't have dynamic variable names in Javascript. 2)There is no need to make variables whose names contain a sequence line `line1,line2,line3` simply create an array and access them using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with the array.

```
var [line1, line2, line3] = MultiLine.attributes.renderers;
```